# Continuity of this function: undefined at $0$ but the plot is regular

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, continuity

I'm having troubles in understanding the continuity at $x = 0$ of this function:
$$f(x) = \frac{x^4 - 3x^2}{6x^3 + x^2}$$

Its domain is $D:x\in(-\infty, -1/6) \cup (-1/6, 0) \cup (0, +\infty)$

We though have $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2(x^2-3)}{x^2(6x+1)} = -3$$

When I plot the function, it does indeed pass through $(0, -3)$ and the curve is smooth. I plotted the function with W. Mathematica.

So it looks like continuous to me.. But for what we studied, since $f(0)$ doesn't exist, we cannot say it's continuous.

Can you enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: $0$ is not in the domain, so the question of continuity at $0$ does not arise.

Comment: Since $0\notin D,$ $f$ is indeed not continuous at $0$, but $g$ defined on $D\cup\{0\}$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in D$ and $g(0)=-3$ is. The plots of $f$ and $g$ look the same (they differ only by one point added for $g$ at the end of the curve).

Comment: @AnneBauval I got confused... When we study the limits of piecewise function at a "critical" point, this point is not in the domain of that piece. For example 
$$ \begin{cases} \frac{1-x^2}{1-x} & x > -1 \\\\ x^2+1 & x \leq -1 \end{cases}$$

Here we study the limits at $x = -1$ but in the first piece $-1$ is not in the domain.

Comment: Contrarily to the continuity at $a$, the question of the limit at $a$ doesn't need $a$ to be in the domain.

Comment: @AnneBauval But the limit at $a$ implies the continuity at $a$, if the limits are finite and identical

Comment: No, again: the continuity at $a$ requires the function to be defined at $a$. In your example in comment, $-1$ is in the domain of $f$: $f(-1)=(-1)^2+1$. But in the example in your post, it is not.

Comment: @AnneBauval There is something unclear to me: exercises like the one I wrote in the comment are typical exercise of continuity. Suppose that in the second piece the domain were $x < -1$. 
What then at $x = -1$?

Comment: The domain to be considered for the continuity at $-1$ is not the "domain of a piece" but the domain of the whole $f.$ In your initial comment, it contained $-1$ and the question of the continuity at $-1$ made sense. In your new comment, $-1\notin D$ and you can only look for the left and right limits, but the continuity makes no sense.

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $a\in D$ and $\lim_af=f(a)$, or equivalently: $a\in D$ and $\lim_{a^+}f=\lim_{a^-}f=f(a).$

Comment: @AnneBauval THANK YOU!! This really clarified me a bunchof things the professor left out... sigh.

Comment: You may or may not have a workflow problem.  Taking your statement at face value, that the professor left out pertinent definitions, it is very hard to believe that you were not also given some sort of textbook or printed notes that gave an unambiguous definition of the continuity of a function at a point.  Assuming so, then you attempted to attack the problem without a comprehensive knowledge of the pertinent portion of the textbook.  This is a large mistake.  Going forward, as you study math, this sort of approach will lead to you constantly *going off the rails*.